# iOS: Callback of 'When all subviews have been added' for a UIView

Tags: ios, swift, custom-view

I am creating a custom view by overriding a `UIVIew` class in Swift.

And in `init?(coder: NSCoder)`, `subviews.count` is zero, while `didAddSubview(subview: UIView)` is called only for direct children.

Is there any callback, when all of the children (even children of child) have been added to the view ?

Or, is there any callback that is called after the view is 'loaded from storyboard' and all of the subviews have been laid out to the view, so that `subviews.count` is not zero ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> and all of the subviews have been laid out to the view

That would be `layoutSubviews`. Be sure to call `super`. If you want to do this only the first time, use a flag.